# Refresh a Bean without configuration change with @RefreshScope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a `@Configuration` class as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class SampleKieConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public KieServices kieServices() {
        return KieServices.Factory.get();
    }

    @Bean
    public KieContainer kieContainer() {

        ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices().newReleaseId("groupId", "artifactId", "version");
        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices().newKieContainer(releaseId);
        kieServices().newKieScanner(kieContainer).start(10_000);
        return  kieContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    public KieBase kieBase() {

        KieBaseConfiguration kieBaseConfiguration = kieServices().newKieBaseConfiguration();
        kieBaseConfiguration.setOption(EqualityBehaviorOption.EQUALITY);
        kieBaseConfiguration.setOption(EventProcessingOption.CLOUD);
        return kieContainer().newKieBase(kieBaseConfiguration);
    }
}
```

`kieServices().newKieScanner(kieContainer).start(10_000);` line basically polls a remote maven repository and refreshes the `kieContainer` object every 10 seconds, if there's a new artifact.

And in somewhere in my upper layers (such as services layer), I have:

```
@Service
@RefreshScope
public class SampleService {

    @Autowired
    private KieBase kBase;

}
```

The `kBase` object is not refreshed (at least not with the new `kieContainer` object) as far as I can see, when I make a call to `/refresh` endpoint. I don't have a centralized configuration, and I am getting a warning on it when I call `/refresh`. What I want to achieve is to have a new `kBase` object every time `kieContainer` is refreshed. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refresh doesn't traverse a hierarchy. It simply clears a cache and on the next reference (via the proxy it creates) the bean is recreated. In your case, since `KieBase` isn't `@RefreshScope`, it isn't recreated. So add `@RefreshScope` to the `KieBase` declaration. If `SampleService` doesn't really need to be recreated, remove the `@RefreshScope` annotation.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the answer. But now I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy11 cannot be cast to some.package.KnowledgeBaseImpl`. Any thoughts?

Comment: is there any way to programmatically refresh the bean? i tried to get the bean from BeanFactory but it holds also the old one (not refreshed.)

Comment: There is the ability to refresh a bean by type https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/8ec45e03b00f3ad96bbc03a86390ed029364bb89/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/context/scope/refresh/RefreshScope.java#L140

Answer (score 0):

as the documentation states:

```
@RefreshScope works (technically) on an @Configuration class, but it might lead to surprising behaviour:
e.g. it does not mean that all the @Beans defined in that class are themselves @RefreshScope.
Specifically, anything that depends on those beans cannot rely on them being updated when a refresh is initiated,
unless it is itself in @RefreshScope (in which it will be rebuilt on a refresh and its dependencies re-injected,
at which point they will be re-initialized from the refreshed @Configuration).
```

So I guess you'd have to annotate a `@RefreshScope` also directly on the `KieBase` @Bean.